# iOS zip subdirectory documents folder

Tags: ios, zip

I'm using ZipKit for iOS I'm trying to zip a subdirectory of my Documents folder. I've referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565568/how-to-zip-a-directory-in-ios-with-zipkit) but it still doesn't seem to be working. My code is:

```
ZKFileArchive *archive = [ZKFileArchive archiveWithArchivePath:@"Documents/test.zip"];
NSInteger result = [archive deflateDirectory:@"/Documents/test" relativeToPath:@"/Documents" usingResourceFork:NO];
```

I have a "test" subdirectory and I want to zip it up into test.zip. The "result" returns 1, but no zip folder appears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For anyone with the same problem, you just need to set the relative path to the actual documents folder:

```
NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentFolder = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];

ZKFileArchive *archive = [ZKFileArchive archiveWithArchivePath:@"Documents/test.zip"];
NSInteger result = [archive deflateDirectory:@"/Documents/test" relativeToPath:documentFolder usingResourceFork:NO];
```