# How to zip a folder using ZipKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, compression, zip

Id like to zip a folder using ZipKit??

I cant seem to locate a good documentation for the usage of functions in the ZipKit library.
Can some one explain the method for folder zipping?

```
ZKFileArchive *archive = [ZKFileArchive archiveWithArchivePath:filePath];
[archive deflateDirectory:param1 relativeToPath:param2 usingResourceFork:NO];
```

What needs to be passed in param1 and param2??I dont understand the function call here?

It would be great if some one could post an example for it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking at the answer in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565568/how-to-zip-a-directory-in-ios-with-zipkit), here's a good example to work with.

Your param1 is the folder (with it's path) to be archived, and the relative path could be the parent folder.

```
NSString *zipFilePath = @"/Documents/zipped.zip";
ZKFileArchive *archive = [ZKFileArchive archiveWithArchivePath:zipFilePath];
NSInteger result = [archive deflateDirectory:@"/Documents/myfolder" relativeToPath:@"/Documents" usingResourceFork:NO];
```

It would be nice if ZipKit had better documentation than [the limited info it has](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/UsingZipKit).

Answer (score 1):

I created the following category method for `NSFileManager` using `ZipKit`.

```
- (BOOL)zipContentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)directory toPath:(NSString *)filename recursive:(BOOL)recursive {
    // If there is already a file at the destination, delete it
    if ([self fileExistsAtPath:filename]) {
        [self removeItemAtPath:filename error:nil];
    }

    @try {
        ZKFileArchive *archive = [ZKFileArchive archiveWithArchivePath:filename];
        NSInteger result = [archive deflateDirectory:directory relativeToPath:directory usingResourceFork:NO];

        return result == zkSucceeded;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        if ([self fileExistsAtPath:filename]) {
            [self removeItemAtPath:filename error:nil];
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

The `directory` parameter is a path to the directory (and its contents) that you wish to the zip up. The `filename` parameter is a path to the resulting zip file you want as a result.